# Custom lint rule which ensures a specific method is not called

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lint

I want to ensure that a specific method of a specific class is not called in my Android app (both in Java and Kotlin code). Suppose, I've got a class called `Bar` with the two methods: `allowed()` and `disallowed()`. Here is the code:

```
package com;

public class Bar {

    public void disallowed() {
    }

    public void allowed() {
    }
}
```

And suppose client code can call `allowed()` and shouldn't call `disallowed()`. I found Google's source code of the built-in [AddJavascriptInterfaceDetector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/AddJavascriptInterfaceDetector.kt) which is similar to my case.

Here is the code of my lint rule:

**SampleCodeDetector**

```
package com.sample.mobile.lint

import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Category
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Detector
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Implementation
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Issue
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.JavaContext
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Scope
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.SourceCodeScanner
import com.intellij.psi.PsiMethod
import org.jetbrains.uast.UCallExpression


class SampleCodeDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
                // ID: used in @SuppressLint warnings etc
                "Usage of Bar#disallowed()",

                // Title -- shown in the IDE's preference dialog, as category headers in the
                // Analysis results window, etc
                "Usage of Bar#disallowed() - Summary",

                // Full explanation of the issue; you can use some markdown markup such as
                // `monospace`, *italic*, and **bold**.
                "This check highlights the usage of Bar#disallowed()",
                Category.CORRECTNESS,
                8,
                Severity.ERROR,
                Implementation(
                        SampleCodeDetector::class.java,
                        Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE
                )
        )

        const val FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME = "com.Bar"
        const val METHOD_NAME = "disallowed"
    }

    override fun getApplicableMethodNames() = listOf(METHOD_NAME)

    override fun visitMethod(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, method: PsiMethod) {
        val evaluator = context.evaluator
        if (!evaluator.methodMatches(method, FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME, true)) {
            return
        }

        val message = "`Bar.disallowed()` should not be called"
        context.report(ISSUE, node, context.getNameLocation(node), message)

    }
}
```

**SampleIssueRegistry**

```
package com.sample.mobile.lint

import com.android.tools.lint.client.api.IssueRegistry
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Issue

class SampleIssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {

    override val issues: List<Issue> get() = listOf(SampleCodeDetector.ISSUE)
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {

    String lintVersion = "26.1.1"

    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:$lintVersion"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:$lintVersion"
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.60"

    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint:$lintVersion"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:$lintVersion"


}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

jar {
    manifest {
        // Only use the "-v2" key here if your checks have been updated to the
        // new 3.0 APIs (including UAST)
        attributes("Lint-Registry-v2": "com.sample.mobile.lint.SampleIssueRegistry")
    }
}
```

**SampleCodeDetectorTest**

```
package com.sample.mobile.lint

import com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.LintDetectorTest
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Detector

class SampleCodeDetectorTest : LintDetectorTest() {

    private val javaFile = "package com.sample.mobile.app;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "import android.util.Log;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "import com.Bar;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class Foo {\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    public void calLLog() {\n" +
            "        int a = 2;\n" +
            "        int b = 8;\n" +
            "        Log.d(\"Tag\", \"a+b=\" + (a + b));\n" +
            "        \n" +
            "        Bar bar = new Bar();\n" +
            "        bar.allowed();\n" +
            "        bar.disallowed();\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n"

    fun testJava() {
        lint().files(LintDetectorTest.java(javaFile))
                .run()
                .expect("")
    }

    override fun getDetector(): Detector? {
        return SampleCodeDetector()
    }

    override fun getIssues() = listOf(SampleCodeDetector.ISSUE)
}
```

Unfortunately, the test fails:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :
Actual   :No warnings.
```

Of course, the expected result is not an empty string, but, anyway, "No warnings." is incorrect since there is a call to `Bar#disallowed()` in `class Foo`

Comment: I know that doesnt answer the question, but imho the simplest solution would be making the method not `public` but some other visibility and encapsulate it that way.

Comment: @leonardkraemer what if I want an Android SDK method not to be called?

Comment: The Android source code uses the `@hide` annotation.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev just making sure that this is not an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ;).

Comment: @Roland the object and the string are arguments of `addJavascriptInterface`. `disallowed()` doesn't have any arguments

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev what about wrapping the class in question in another class, without exposing that particular method you would like to avoid ?

Comment: have look at @RestrictTo annotation

Answer (score 2):

You should also include source code of `com.Bar` class into your test:

```
import com.android.tools.lint.checks.infrastructure.LintDetectorTest
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Detector

class SampleCodeDetectorTest : LintDetectorTest() {

    private val javaFile = """
        package com.sample.mobile.app;

        import android.util.Log;

        import com.Bar;

        public class Foo {

            public void calLLog() {
                int a = 2;
                int b = 8;
                Log.d("Tag", "a+b=" + (a + b));

                Bar bar = new Bar();
                bar.allowed();
                bar.disallowed();
            }
        }
    """.trimIndent()

    private val barJavaFile = """
        package com;

        public class Bar {

            public void disallowed() {
            }

            public void allowed() {
            }
        }
    """.trimIndent()

    fun testJava() {
        lint().files(java(javaFile), java(barJavaFile))
                .run()
                .expect("""
                    src/com/sample/mobile/app/Foo.java:16: Error: Bar.disallowed() should not be called [Usage of Bar#disallowed()]
                            bar.disallowed();
                                ~~~~~~~~~~
                    1 errors, 0 warnings
                """.trimIndent())
    }

    override fun getDetector(): Detector? {
        return SampleCodeDetector()
    }

    override fun getIssues() = listOf(SampleCodeDetector.ISSUE)
}
```

Lint just does not know what `com.Bar` is and silently ignores it.