# Linting rule to ban specific method in Kotlin (not Android)

Tags: kotlin, static-analysis, lint

I am trying to add a linting rule to my Kotlin/Gradle project to ban a specific method from ever being called (specifically DateTimeTz.local from the Klock library - it has been causing some timezone issues due to devs calling it without fully understanding its purpose and I would like to add a barrier to make it harder to accidentally use). This is in the core code of a Kotlin Multiplatform app, so no access to Android libraries.

Ideally, I'd like it to be possible to override this rule.

This looks like the sort of thing I want to do, except it's not Android code: [Custom lint rule which ensures a specific method is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909950/custom-lint-rule-which-ensures-a-specific-method-is-not-called)

Does anyone have any recommendations for a good library/approach for this problem? I'm quite new to linting rules in Kotlin.